# org-caldav/oauth2/plstore asking for passphrase many times

Tags: org-mode

I have been struggling to set up org-caldav with (multiple) google calendar(s) for some time. Syncing works, but one remaining annoying problem is that I am asked for the passphrase many (5-many) times, even though I have set `plstore-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption`. Does anyone recognise the problem and/or have a fix?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, emacs-version 25.1.1, org-version: 9.1.14.

Answer (score 1):

After extensive debugging I found the culprit to be that my gpg-agent was called multiple times. One clue was that the passphrase was asked for in a *popup window* and not in the Emacs message bar! The following sequence solved my problem:

In my terminal (bash shell)

```
$ unset GPG_AGENT_INFO
$ emacs
```

In Emacs

```
M-x org-caldav-sync
```

Now I am asked for the passphrase **once** in the Emacs message bar!

(Also see: https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav/issues/117.)

**Edit:** Adding

```
(setenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO")
```

to my .emacs also worked.